# Testing if scroll is up or down in Mac OS?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm using this code to check for scrolling:

```
scrollKeyMonitor = [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSScrollWheelMask handler:^(NSEvent *incomingEvent)
                    {
                        //printf("we are scrolling!");

                        return incomingEvent;

                    }];
```

How do I check the y values of the scroll to see if we are going up or down?

Thanks

Comment: Note that this will trigger if the user scrolls anywhere in your application, not only a specific view or window. This includes the Font Panel and Spelling Panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an initial position.  Then test to see if the current position is lower / higher to determine if user is scrolling up or down.  Then reset the initial position to the current position for the next movement.

Comment: how do I access the y values of the scroll?

Comment: Look at deltaX / deltaY of the NSEvent.  In fact, they already give you the delta (change from initial to current.)